# Need help while building my doc2vec embedding model for Holy Quran verses retrieval system based on verse's topic

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, arabic, doc2vec

I have an important Module in my Graduation Project, It is about to learn a model that helps me to give it an input/query which expected to be an "Islamic" topic and the model's outputs are some Verses from the "Holy Quran" that related to my topic.

### An Example (in Arabic)

Query may be something like this: بر الوالدين, or الإحسان بالوالين

The Expected output some Quran verses related to the previous query like this:

- وَاعْبُدُوا اللَّهَ وَلَا تُشْرِكُوا بِهِ شَيْئًا وَبِالْوَالِدَيْنِ إِحْسَانً
- وَقُلْ لَهُمَا قَوْلًا كَرِيمًا
- وَوَصَّيْنَا الْإِنْسَانَ بِوَالِدَيْهِ حُسْنًا

This is a simple example, but note that the topic may be not be mentioned itself in the verse's text, so it may be more difficult than the above example.

### My Data Set

Till now. I have collected an **Arabic, Islamic** data such as:

- Sayings of the Prophet Mohammed: about 35000 Arabic Documents, this is a sample from the data file:

حدثنا سعيد بن يحيى بن سعيد القرشي، قال حدثنا أبي قال، حدثنا أبو بردة بن عبد الله بن أبي بردة، عن أبي بردة، عن أبي موسى  رضى الله عنه  قال قالوا يا رسول الله أى الإسلام أفضل قال ‏"‏ من سلم المسلمون من لسانه ويده ‏"‏‏.
‏

حدثنا عمرو بن خالد، قال حدثنا الليث، عن يزيد، عن أبي الخير، عن عبد الله بن عمرو  رضى الله عنهما  أن رجلا، سأل النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم أى الإسلام خير قال ‏"‏ تطعم الطعام، وتقرأ السلام على من عرفت ومن لم تعرف ‏"‏‏.
‏

حدثنا مسدد، قال حدثنا يحيى، عن شعبة، عن قتادة، عن أنس  رضى الله عنه  عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم‏.‏وعن حسين المعلم، قال حدثنا قتادة، عن أنس، عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال ‏"‏ لا يؤمن أحدكم حتى يحب لأخيه ما يحب لنفسه ‏"‏‏.
‏

حدثنا أبو اليمان، قال أخبرنا شعيب، قال حدثنا أبو الزناد، عن الأعرج، عن أبي هريرة  رضى الله عنه  أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال ‏"‏ فوالذي نفسي بيده لا يؤمن 
أحدكم حتى أكون أحب إليه من والده وولده ‏"‏‏.‏

- I have also the Holy Quran Meanings data set, about 7000 documents, and here is a sample of this documents:

الحمد لله جملة خبرية قصد بها الثناء على الله بمضمونها من انه تعالى مالك لجميع الحمد من الخلق او مستحق لان يحمدوه والله علم على المعبود بحق رب العالمين اي مالك جميع الخلق من الانس والجن والملائكة والدواب وغيرهم وكل منها يطلق عليه عالم يقال عالم الانس وعالم الجن الى غير ذلك وغلب في جمعه بالياء والنون 
اولي العلم على غيرهم وهو من العلامة لانه علامة على موجده

الرحمن الرحيم اي ذي الرحمة وهي ارادة الخير لاهله

اي الجزاء وهو يوم القيامة وخص بالذكر لانه لا ملك ظاهرا فيه لاحد الا الله تعالى بدليل لمن الملك اليوم؟ لله ومن قرا مالك فمعناه الامر كله في يوم القيامة او هو موصوف بذلك دائما كغافر الذنب فصح وقوعه صفة لمعرفة

اياك نعبد واياك نستعين اي نخصك بالعبادة من توحيد وغيره ونطلب المعونة على العبادة وغيرها

اهدنا الصراط المستقيم اي ارشدنا اليه ويبدل منه

صراط الذين انعمت عليهم بالهداية ويبدل من الذين بصلته غير المغضوب عليهم وهم اليهود ولا وغير الضالين وهم النصارى ونكتة البدل افادة ان المهتدين ليسوا يهودا ولا نصارى والله اعلم بالصواب واليه المرجع والماب وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وعلى اله وصحبه وسلم تسليما كثيرا دائما ابدا وحسبنا الله ونعم الوكيل ولا حول ولا قوة الا بالله العلي العظيم

- I collected also manual annotated topics for each verse from an Islamic expert who classified the whole Quran verses to 11 main sections, each section my have subsections and subsubsections, ... so I have a 2-column data set, the first is the verse itself and the second is it's annotated topic. this is a sample:
  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tEYs2QV9AmGQFqSzpvscNtlZfO3fVgCE

note that, in the `ManualKeyword` column the topic which is after `-` mark is a subsection of the topic which is before `-`

### Doc2Vec Model

After many tries to achieve my goal, I read about `doc2vec` model and read it's paper and saw some implementations to it on Arabic tasks. I think my problem will be solved if I train a `doc2vec` model on the whole Arabic, Islamic data sets which I collected for now and any other data sets related to this field.

My Idea after training my model is to use it to embed each Manual annotated topic **individuality** (For clarification: I will separate each row like this `أركان الاسلام-التوحيد-الكافرون-افتراؤهم علي الله و تكذيبهم و جدالهم` to single phrases

```
أركان الاسلام
التوحيد
الكافرون
افتراؤهم علي الله وتكذيبهم وجدالهم
```

and embed/represent each single topic with a vector)
then embed user's query (which is expected to be more than one word) to it's vector using my trained model. Then calculate the **Cosine Similarity** between Query's Vector and each topics' vector. so I can map the topic which gets the highest similarity to it's related verses and retrieve them to the user.

### My Code

**After reading quran meanings and the Sayings of the Prophet data in** `hadithsDocumentsList`:

```
#Converting docuemnts list into tagged documents (each document is splited)
tagged_data = [gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(words=_d.split(),
                              tags=[str(i)]) for i, _d in enumerate(hadithsDocumentsList)]

cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()     #Getting number of cores

model = Doc2Vec(dm=1, size=200, window=10, workers=6)    #Initialize the model
model.build_vocab(tagged_data)      #Bulding vocabulary
print("model.corpus_count" , model.corpus_count)

#Training the model
model.train(tagged_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=10)


#Saving Model
model.save("HadithAndTafserModel")
print("Model Saved")

model= Doc2Vec.load("HadithAndTafserModel")

testData = " رسول الله محمد".split()
testDataVector = model.infer_vector(testData)
print("Query Vector: ", testDataVector)

mostSemilarDocs = model.wv.most_similar([testDataVector])
print("MOST SIMILAR DOCUMENTS: \n")
print(mostSemilarDocs)
```

After training the model and getting a vector for a query from my choice and using `most_similar` function to get similar documents from my model. the output is definitely not what I expected. and model's accuracy is very bad.

I don't know what are the correct parameters like `dm`, `dbow_words`, `size`, `window`, `alpha` that should be passed to the model to achieve the highest accuracy. I little understanding each parameter's functionality and need help to tune each of them. I also want to know if my dataset is enough to build this model or I need to increase it? is there any inaccuracy or mistakes while collecting or passing them to the model?

What are your suggestions or opinions?

Answer (score 1):

Note I don't know Arabic, so can't interpret your example text fragments.

Much `Doc2Vec` published work uses datasets of tens-of-thousands to millions of training docs, but sometimes people reports some success with even smaller datasets.

So, your 7000-entry "Holy Quran Meanings" dataset, which if I understand correctly maps original verses to more-recently-written interpretations (where the interpretations are more likely to match 'query' texts), is plausibly enough, especially if extended with the other annotations.

There's no universally-good guide to what the model training parameters should be – it varies a lot based on the size/quality of your data, and your ultimate goals. The best practice is to figure some quantitative, repeatable way to score the model's vectors, that correlates well with your end goal.

(For example, perhaps you have a growing list of results that "should" rank more highly for certain queries than other results. You then score any model based on how many of these golden-standard preferences it gets "right", and try many permutations of model parameters to find the model that scores highest.)

Your performance may be very sensitive to proper tokenization & synthetic-document construction strategies, to make sure you get the most value from limited data. (For example, ensuring different forms of the same word are canonicalized together, rather than remaining independent and then perhaps not reaching the `min_count` cutoff. Or, combining multiple annotations for the same verse into one varied/rich-in-meaning document of meaningful length, rather than fragmented tiny few-word documents.)

Some general tendencies of model parameters:

- with less data – fewer docs, smaller vocabularies, smaller documents – you may need to decrease the vector sizes and/or increase the number of training epochs
- often plain PV-DBOW mode (`dm=0`) works fast & well, especially with shorter documents. (In pure PV-DBOW, there is no word-to-word training, so the `window` is irrelevant. If in PV-DM `dm=1` mode, or if adding word-to-word training in PV-DBOW with `dbow_words=1`, then `window` is again relevant, and often longer windows make vectors more about general topics than narrow substitutable entities.)
- larger corpuses may benefit from more-aggressive discards of rare words (higher `min_count`) or more-aggressive downsampling of frequent words (smaller `sample` parameter)

If you're using `infer_vector()`, be sure to use a recent version of `gensim` (there have been important fixes and changes to the defaults). Be sure to preprocess/canonicalize/tokenize the text the same for `infer_vector()` as was done during training (because unknown words will be ignored, making inference more random. Inference works better with longer text more like training data (comapared to a few words), and may benefit from more inference `epochs` (especially on very-short documents).

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I want to ask you a question. do you thing that `doc2vec` is the appropriate model? or it will be better to train a `word2vec` model to do this task?

Comment: It's plausible `Doc2Vec` could work - many have reported success with it providing a semantic, fuzzy search (especially as an enhancement to traditional keyword search). But only trying it can tell for sure, as success will be very sensitive to your corpus, preprocessing/modeling choices, & goals. `Word2Vec` is a very similar algorithm – many `Doc2Vec` modes also train usable word-vectors – but W2V doesn't automatically give you vectors for multi-word texts/queries, so you'd need to make other decisions about how to use word-vectors for your purposes.

Comment: I think that `doc2vec` not appropriate for my case. I have long documents in the training set and I expect a short query from the user. there is a gap between the two types of documents. can you tell me what are the methods that used to combine word vectors to represent a query that contain more than one word in only one vector?